# How to use the value not displayed by a dropdown when connected to access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My program uses a database in access which consists of BreedID and BreedName. I have a dropdown box in vb.net which shows the name for the user to select, however in my code I would like to store the ID related to that name so that I can send it over to the access database using oledb. Currently this is what it looks like:

Dim BrVar As String = Breed.SelectedItem.Text

But that isn't working! Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add hidden columns to your dropdown box, it may already exist. The first column in a dropdown box is `column(0)` and you can set the width to 0cm. This can be for the ID value. Leaving `column(1)` for the Name value.

Then you can use `Breed.SelectedItem.column(0)`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is on the `Data` tab set up your rowsource to `SELECT` both the `BreedID` and `BreedName` fields (in that order). Then make sure `bound column` is set to `1`.

Then on the `Format` tab set `Column Count` to `2` and `Column Widths` to `0;1`.

That will have the result of displaying the `BreedName` field but using the `BreedID` field as the value of the combo box.

Use `Dim BrVar As Long = Breed.SelectedItem` to get the value of `BreedID`.

Comment: There is no option for "rowsource" when I click on my dropdown, and no matter where I look I cannot find a way of making another column! I'm using VB 2010 if that helps. Sorry If I'm just being stupid

Comment: Sorry, my instructions are for using a combo box in an MS Access form. For vb.net you will have to find the equivalent functions/parameters.